# iTunes Connect trouble - 2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected

Tags: ios, crash, launch, crash-log

I have created a game for iPhone in Swift (Xcode 6.4) and there is no error message in Xcode. Everything is working correctly in Simulator and also on real iPhone. Problem is after submitting the package to the iTunes Connect.

I alway get error: 2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected.
"We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue."

Logs:

http://a52.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/fc/77/53/fc7753f6-9d9d-991d-8c02-c1afeae66ea2/temp..ojahvbgy.crash?downloadKey3=1438984413_5da87ab807d97290498f8dbabc60dec7

and

http://a1313.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/7d/79/b2/7d79b24b-e816-0c34-8f51-d9775024c3cb/temp..dxslzkma.crash?downloadKey3=1438984413_b6f3584e263db2c6a0e387b6b725763a

I’m trying to solve my problem over the month and I have still no solution. Any idea? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Symbolicate the crash logs so you can see where in your code it is crashing.

Comment: I would recommend installing Crashlytics. It gives much better stack traces to help track down these types of issues.

Comment: Same thing is happening with us. The crash logo is bogus and offers no help what-so-ever, I've personally run the app on 10 different devices, including the ones they used and it ran perfectly fine. I think this is just Apple's new trick for rejecting apps that they don't want on the appstore but don't qualify for a rejection under their current terms and conditions.